# Multiple audio stream in Universal App(Runtime API), XNA SoundEffect replacement

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

As the XNA `SoundEffect` is no longer available in the Windows Runtime API (for developing Universal App), I need something similar to play multiple audio streams at the same time.

Requirements:
Play the same audio file multiple times, simultaneously.

Previous Silverlight implementation with `SoundEffect`:

```
// Play sound 10 times, sound can be played together.
// i.e. First sound continues playing while second sound starts playing.
for(int i=0; i++; i < 10)
{
    Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("sounds/Ding.wav");
    SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    effect.Play();
    // Wait a while before playing again.
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

`SoundEffect` supports multiple (up to 16 I think) `SoundEffectInstance` being played simultaneously.

The standard `MediaElement` API only supports 1 audio stream for Windows Phone 8.1.

I bumped into this: https://github.com/rajenki/audiohelper which uses the XAudio2 API but it doesn't seem to support simultaneous audio either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. I used SharpDX. Huge thanks to the author here: http://www.hoekstraonline.net/2013/01/13/how-to-play-a-wav-sound-file-with-directx-in-c-for-windows-8/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=how-to-play-a-wav-sound-file-with-directx-in-c-for-windows-8

Here is the code to the solution:

Initialization:

```
        xAudio = new XAudio2();
        var masteringVoice = new MasteringVoice(xAudio);
        var nativeFileStream = new NativeFileStream("Assets/Ding.wav", NativeFileMode.Open, NativeFileAccess.Read, NativeFileShare.Read);

        stream = new SoundStream(nativeFileStream);
        waveFormat = stream.Format;
        buffer = new AudioBuffer
        {
            Stream = stream.ToDataStream(),
            AudioBytes = (int)stream.Length,
            Flags = BufferFlags.EndOfStream
        };
```

Event handler:

```
        var sourceVoice = new SourceVoice(xAudio, waveFormat, true);


        sourceVoice.SubmitSourceBuffer(buffer, stream.DecodedPacketsInfo);
        sourceVoice.Start();
```

The officially provided code by SharpDX's sample does not use NativeFileStream, it is required to make it work.